# project euler qn 23

Tags: javascript, algorithm

A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

PROBLEM: my answer seems to be significantly larger than the correct one, 4179871, would appreciate if someone points out the mistake in my code. Thank you very much!

```
var abundanceArray = [];
var sumOfAbundanceArray = [];
var totalSum = 0;
var limit = 28123;

function checkRepeat(x) {
  if (sumOfAbundanceArray.length === 0) return false;

  for (var n = 0; n < sumOfAbundanceArray.length; n++) {
    if (x === sumOfAbundanceArray[n]) return true;
  }

  return false;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
  var sum = 0;
  totalSum += i;

  for (var j = 1; j <= Math.ceil(i/2); j++) {
    if (i % j < 1) {
      sum += j;
      if (sum > i) {
        abundanceArray.push(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

var total = abundanceArray.length;

for (var k = 0; k < total; k++) {
  if (abundanceArray[k] * 2 > limit) break;

  for (var l = k; l < total; l++) {
    var sumOfAbundance = abundanceArray[k] + abundanceArray[l];

    if (sumOfAbundance > limit || checkRepeat(sumOfAbundance) === true) break;
    sumOfAbundanceArray.push(sumOfAbundance);
    totalSum -= sumOfAbundance;
  }
}

console.log(totalSum);
```

Comment: try to print all abundant numbers less than 28123

Comment: Do not present uncommented code. (Comment on _what_ "everything" _is there for_ - most can read what things _are_ (if not what they are supposed to be).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the mistake lies in the last break you've entered into the code (the longest line).

sumOfAbundance is a sum of two abundant numbers, and indeed you want to limit the search to make the program run faster. But - you should break the loop only in case sumOfAbundance is greater than limit. That's when you know your abundant values are too large.

You should *not* break the loop in the other case of the condition. It checks that sumOfAbundance was (or was not) counted before, but no matter if you've seen the value of sumOfAbundance before, you *must continue the loop* if sumOfAbundance is still small enough.

So to conclude: check both parts of this condition before pushing to sumOfAbundanceArray and changing the totalSum, but break out of the loop only if sumOfAbundance is too large.

Comment: Thank you so much Brenner!! It has been driving me crazy haha